# PHP Null Coalesce Confusion

Tags: php, wordpress, null-coalescing-operator

I'm trying to understand why, in Wordpress, when using PHP's Null Coalescing operator, this snippet works:

```
 $pageTitle = $atts['pageTitle'] ?? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pageTitle', true);
 if (empty($pageTitle)) { $pageTitle = get_the_title($post->ID); };
```

But this one doesn't: (returns empty)

```
 $pageTitle = $atts['pageTitle'] ?? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pageTitle', true) ?? get_the_title($post->ID);
```

I thought you could chain them together? I know there's something about different types of variable allowed, but it's confusing to me why `get_post_meta` works fine in this context but `get_the_title` does not.

`get_the_title($post->ID)` is indeed returning the correct value when needed, but only in the first example.

edit: this is in the context of a shortcode function, if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: `$pageTitle = ($atts['pageTitle'] ?? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pageTitle', true)) ?? get_the_title($post->ID);` Use parenthesis for logical order

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately no dice with that either.

Comment: The only difference I can see between the two snippets is that the second won't work if `get_post_meta` is returning something empty-ish, but not null (e.g. an empty string, or zero, etc). You can definitely chain the operator together like that.

Comment: Ah ha, that's it. It's returning an empty string (which I forgot about get_post_meta) and false/empty does not necessarily equal null. Thank you for that brain nudge!

Comment: Though chaining does indeed work it is quite likely to cause confusion when you, or someone else, comes back to it in 6 months time (or next week) :)